# Multiple assignments using with() in Groovy

Tags: groovy

Seen good working [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556816/groovy-multiple-assignment-with-a-map) in groovy using *with*.

**Question:** However, having trouble or could not understand the reason for not giving desired output when using it with the combination of keyword **this.with{..}** as shown below:

Here is the code for **Person.groovy**

```groovy
class Person {

    def name
    def address
    def mail

    Person(name, address, mail){
        this.with {
            name = name
            address = address
            mail = mail
        }
    }

    String toString() {
        "${name} ${address} ${mail}"
    }
}
```

When you call the above class with below code, output is coming as **`null null null`** instead of **`abc xyz abc@example.com`**

```groovy
def person1 = new Person('abc', 'xyz', 'abc@example.com')
println person1.toString()
```

Comment: If that's all the constructor is doing, you can use the   `@groovy.transform.TupleConstructor` annotation on the class and not code the constructor at all. Groovy will do it for you :)

Comment: Emmanuel Rosa, I completely understand your point, most of the times **tupple constructor** is used. The above example is to show problem only. There are such situations that constructor is required. As mentioned in one of the comments below answers, it happened to replace `.with{..}` in _other parts of code_ as well in _Constructors_ and causing problem did not get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
class Person {

    def name
    def address
    def mail

    Person(name, address, mail){
        with {
            this.name = name
            this.address = address
            this.mail = mail
        }
    }

    String toString() {
        "${name} ${address} ${mail}"
    }
}

def person1 = new Person('abc', 'xyz', 'abc@example.com')
println person1.toString()
```

Since groovy doesn't know how to distinguish `name` from object from `name` argument passed to constructor.

You can also try:

```
Person(namea, addressa, maila){
    with {
        name = namea
        address = addressa
        mail = maila
    }
}
```

If you change the variables names (I mean class fields will be called differently than constructor args) you don't `with` nor this.

Comment: Opal, thank you for the response. I understand other formats works well. Looks, this case particularly an exception, seemed to be not a case to use?

Comment: The piece of code you provided will not work correctly.

Comment: Ok. Just seeking another clarification from your answer. Also you provided new way like using `with { .. }` unlike `this.with { ..}`. Does this way work always or just `this.` is optional just in this case? i.e., there is some object say `def person2 = new Person(null, null, null); `. Now want to set data for `person2` object.

Comment: `this.` is optional in this case.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Understand that object `person2` reference is needed(can't be omitted like `this` keyword) in the case mentioned in earlier comment like `person2.with {\(name, address, mail\) = ['abc', 'xyz', 'abc@example.com']}`

Comment: @Rao, I don't understand what you mean with this `person2`?

Comment: Like I mentioned earlier in comment, `def person2 = new Person(null, null, null);person2.with {\(name, address, mail\) = ['abc', 'xyz', 'abc@example.com']}`, to see if object name can be omitted in here like we omitted for `this.`

Comment: Interestingly if **name** property is marked _final_ like `final def name` and `Person(namea, addressa, maila){
    with {
        name = namea
        address = addressa
        mail = maila
    }
}` - failed to compile. says `cannot modify final field 'name' outside of constructor.`

Comment: That's all ok. You can't initialize final variable elsewhere, only in constructor block.

Comment: But what we were changing as part this answer in constructor only, right? i.e., `with` is inside of _Constructor_. I just copied part from above answer or just added `final` for a property and code is not compiling.

Comment: It's about *being* in constructor but about assigning in *constructor*.

Comment: Ok, looks this is a limitation if `.with{..}` needs to be used in the above case.

Answer (score 2):

Groovy can't resolve the same identifier to two different elements. You could try with the `setX` instead:

```
class Person {
    def name
    def address
    def mail

    Person(name, address, mail){
        setName name
        setAddress address
        setMail mail
    }

    String toString() { "$name $address $mail" }
}

assert new Person('abc', 'xyz', 'abc@example.com').toString() ==
    'abc xyz abc@example.com'
```

Comment: Will, thank you for your response. Was refactoring some existing code which contains both _Java_ and _Groovy_ classes. And found such code in Constructors of _Groovy_ . Was just replacing `.with{..}` and suddenly happened to test and found not working. +1 for suggesting `setX`

Comment: When `setX` is used, `with{..}` may not even needed.