# Why do I get a compilation error when trying to assign multiple values to class members?

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to do multiple assignment from a function, it works fine when done as follows:

```
def f() {
    return [2,3]
}

(a, b) = f()
```

However, if I try essentially the same thing, but try to assign to class members instead, I get a compilation error:

```
class Foo{
    def A
    def B
}

def f() {
    return [2,3]
}

foo = new Foo()

(foo.A, foo.B) = f()
```

The error I get is `Missing ')' at line: 12, column: 7`. What's the problem here? Thanks.

Comment: Currently you cant use multiple assignments to assign class variables. This has never been implemented in Groovy.
You can also check this issue out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556816/groovy-multiple-assignment-with-a-map

Comment: The first answer to that question should provide a work-around in your case.

Comment: @zana Ah, great. Thanks!